# iPhone app crashes when i try to switch between two apps?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, xcode4.3

iPhone app crashes when i try to switch between two apps one is my own app and other app which is  downloaded from iTunes. Suppose my app has 2 view namely view A and view B .first I redirect my app from view A to view B then I pause my app and open another app. Then I resume my app and want to go back to view A. when I  click the back button that point of time my app crashes. I can't find any reason for that and also checked all memory management & its seems OK.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this is a very vague question and I doubt that anyone can help you unless you provide any code

Comment: Actually if I have to send my code then I have to send my project.

Comment: Provide code of how you are navigating from A view to B view.

Comment: [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]; This for back to the view A from the view B

Comment: [self.navigationController pushViewController:Bviewidentifier animated:YES]; This is the code for going the view from A to B

Comment: Try running the app with zombies enabled.  The system may be unloading something you don't expect when putting your app into the background.

Comment: How can i enable zombies with my app. Is there any configuration i have to change in settings or I have to write any code.